# I am getting Duplicate JSON body with annotation @JsonProperty("Body")

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

with capital `B(@JsonProperty("Body"))` in annotation I see duplicate json body like this

```
{"Body":{
    "Element": "Value",
    .
    .
}},{"body":{
    "Element": "Value",
    .
    .
}}
```

with small b in `annotion(@JsonProperty("body"))` I see no issue
Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: Probably you have no `Body`property but a there already is `body` property. Hard to say without seeing your code.

Comment: Thanks @zeroflagL , issue was with placement of annotation. Earlier I was using annotation before variable name and now when I tried with placing it before getter it's working